# Django view doesn't contain a HTTP_REFERRER header

Tags: python, django, http

I'm testing a view that is accessing `request.META` where I want to get the `HTTP_REFERRER` header. The purpose being that I want to redirect to a previous page in case the queryset within the *search_list* view returns empty. A referring page happens to contain a form which is submitted through a `GET` request. The cleaned data is then passed to `search_list` as a query string.

When testing the view, all test assertions pass. However when I `python manage.py runserver` and simulate the test case I get an error: `KeyError at /minerals/search; 'HTTP_REFERRER'`. I'm trying to understand why I'm getting a KeyError when running the server?

I tried using *HTTP_REFERER* and *HTTP_REFERRER* for keys but both fail.

Also noting this:

```
Internal Server Error: /minerals/search/
"GET /minerals/search/?query=Kryptonite HTTP/1.1" 500
```

**test_views.py**

```
class SearchFormResults(TestCase):

    def test_user_search_query_fail(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse("minerals:search_list"), data={'query': 'Kryptonite'},
            HTTP_REFERRER=reverse(
                "minerals:letter_list", kwargs={'query': 'N'}
            ), follow=True
        )
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse(
                "minerals:letter_list", kwargs={'query': 'N'}
            )
        )
        self.assertTemplateUsed("minerals/list.html")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No minerals exist with the provided search.")
```

**views.py**

```
def search_list(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('query')
    matched_minerals = Mineral.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(image_caption__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(category__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(formula__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(strunz_classification__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(crystal_system__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(unit_cell__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(color__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(crystal_symmetry__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(cleavage__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(mohs_scale_hardness__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(luster__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(streak__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(diaphaneity__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(optical_properties__icontains=search_query)|
        Q(group__icontains=search_query)
    )

    if not matched_minerals:
        messages.info(request, "No minerals exist with the provided search.")
        previous_page = request.META["HTTP_REFERRER"]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(previous_page)
    else:
        search_form = SearchForm()
        return render(
            request, 'minerals/list.html', 
            {'minerals': matched_minerals, 'form': search_form}
        )
```

Comment: It is `HTTP_REFERER` (yes, a historical typo). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: Edited this post to make note of that. I get a KeyError either way.

Comment: Presumably it's because there is no referrer? If you visit this URL directly rather than from a link, this key will not be set. So you need to check it conditionally. i.e., `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')`